# Allow Users To select Player Skin Found nil on if Statement

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to allow the player to select a skin from a UIViewController than when the sprite is called it is loaded with their selected skin.

**ball.swift**

```
    var skin : Skins!


init(ballName name : String?, ballColor color : UIColor, ballMass mass : CGFloat, ballPosition pos : CGPoint) {
   if skin.dogSkin == true{
                super.init(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "doge"), color: color, size: CGSize(width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2))

        print("was called here too")
    }
    else{
    super.init(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "circle"), color: color, size: CGSize(width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2))
    }
```

**Skins.swift**

```
var dogSkin = false
@IBAction func backbutton(sender: AnyObject) {

}

@IBAction func dogPressed(sender: AnyObject) {


    dogSkin = true
    print("I hit it")
```

}

Now getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value,When the if statement is triggered,  can't use a guard statment on it.

changed it to

```
var skin = Skins()
```

works-- doesn't crash. But doesn't this create a new instance of Skins? Making the BOOL false again?

Get this in the console though? and skin doesn't change.

```
<xxxx.Skins: 0x7fa59d825b30>
<xxxx.Skins: 0x7fa59d828500>
<xxxx.Skins: 0x7fa59d82a7a0>
<xxxx.Skins: 0x7fa59d82c970>
<xxxx.Skins: 0x7fa59d82e960>
<xxxx.Skinss: 0x7fa59d90d7b0>
<xxxx.Skins: 0x7fa59d90ffb0>
<xxxx.Skins: 0x7fa59d912000>
<xxxx.Skins: 0x7fa59d914060>

...
```

Comment: Skin is a dictionary, and you are trying to assign a string array to it. Plus it is a let, which means it cant be changed anyway.

Comment: Show the definition of your Skins type.

Answer (score 2):

You made the variable skin an implicitly unwrapped optional variable. That means that any time you reference it, it assumes the variable contains a valid value and crashes if it does not.

You don't assign a value to skin before trying to reference it, so you crash.

Forget you ever knew about the force-unwrap operator `!` for your first 2 months of programming in Swift. For newbies, it's the crash operator.

Comment: "The crash operator". I'm gonna start using that one.